# NuGet; unable to get package as wrong version reported in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

I'm trying to build a solution but I get this error,

> he 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.14' package requires NuGet client version '2.8.1' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.6.40619.9041'.

I've just upgraded NuGet package manager in Tools/"Extensions and Updates" which reports the version as 2.8.50313.31.

I've restarted VS2012, restarted the computer, cleaned the project and rebuilt, but I still can't get Visual Studio to recognise the new version and hence can't compile.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to use the package manager console and run

> Install-Package Microsoft.Bcl.Build -Version 1.0.14

to get it to work manually.

Edit (5/11/2014). The problem is actually that Nuget gets bundled with the solution and it is this that needs upgrading. I did this by finding the directory in the project with the nuget.exe file in it (.nuget for me, YMMV) going to that directory and running nuget update -self. If you go with the original solution, you have to do this manually for each package. HTH.

Answer (score 8):

1. Run Console (cmd) as Administrator
2. Locate your **.nuget** folder that contains the **NuGet.exe** file *(you may check error message to locate the path)*
3. execute this command `NuGet.exe update -self`

Took me all day to find that NuGet was bound to the individual project.

Comment: Hi, this works for me, just some more precision, this was happening on the build machine for me, using the Package Manager Console inside Visual Studio, i located the .nuget folder, on the sources. cd inside then run the command above specify by @AmpLid `NuGet.exe update -self`and then check-in the new Nuget.exe file.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in VS 2017 Enterprise-

> 1. Right click your solution and go to "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution..."
> 2. In the window that opens up, click the gear icon at the top right corner.
> 3. Select "General" and click the "Clear Clear All NuGet Cache(s)" button. This will run for a few seconds depending on the size of your
>      cache.
> 4. Clean and rebuild your solution.

[image]
[image]